# intranet tomcat accessing issue

Tags: windows-7, tomcat, wireless-networking

I have a wireless router at my home. I hosted apache tomcat server on my laptop running on windows 7. then i tried to put another laptop on to the same wireless network. I am not able to access the machine A from Machine B via tomcat URL. I used the exact 192.x.x.x ip of machine A from Machine B. How to resolve this issue.

I tried to switch off the firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an option in the windows version of Apache where you can select which interface to serve to? It should be set to 192.x.x.x instead of "localhost" so that not just the local computer has access to it.

If you have antivirus that comes with firewall software, port 80 will have to be opened for incoming traffic in the third party software instead of the windows firewall. No more than one firewall should be active at a time, so if two are enabled, disable one of them.

Some firewalls have priority based rules so that rules at the top of the list override rules at the bottom of the list. You can try putting the rule to open up port 80 at the top of the list.

Make sure you can ping the apache server from another computer.

try telneting to the apache server on port 80

```
telnet 192.x.x.x 80
```

If it says "could not open connection to the host" then your server might still be blocking the connection. If the screen goes blank, then its good and pressing ctrl-c and enter might show you some stuff like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a port issue?

Tomcat will run by default on TCP/IP port number 8080, if you just try to connect to `http://ip.of.tomcat.server` it will use port 80.

You have to change your urls to `http://ip.of.tomcat.server:8080`

Comment: This is does only apply if you don't have an apache webserver in front of the tomcat server.